# Fancybox youtube iframe works in all browsers except ie9. Doctype is in place - other suggestions?

Tags: internet-explorer-9, fancybox

I have a page using the fancybox 2 youtube iframe -  it's working perfectly in all browsers other than IE9 and can't figure out what's going on. In IE9, nothing happens - no popup or overlay at all.  IE8 and IE7 work fine, safari, chrome, firefox are all ok.

The page starts with the doctype on the first line - is there anything else particular to IE9 that I should check?

Thanks!

Comment: why you don't post your code or share a link to the site with the issue?  it would be much easier to debug

Answer (score 1):

If it's working in IE7 and IE8, I would check to see if when those are used, they are displaying the page in compatibility mode. If they are not, chances are IE9 is being forced to compatibility mode. You can force standards mode in IE by specificying a meta tag:

```
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >
```

You can also use JavaScript to determine what mode IE is displaying in with :

```
    javascript:alert(document.documentMode);

    <script type="text/javascript">
    engine = null;
if (window.navigator.appName == "Microsoft Internet Explorer")
{
   // This is an IE browser. What mode is the engine in?
   if (document.documentMode) // IE8 or later
      engine = document.documentMode;
   else // IE 5-7
   {
      engine = 5; // Assume quirks mode unless proven otherwise
      if (document.compatMode)
      {
         if (document.compatMode == "CSS1Compat")
            engine = 7; // standards mode
      }
      // There is no test for IE6 standards mode because that mode  
      // was replaced by IE7 standards mode; there is no emulation.
   }
   // the engine variable now contains the document compatibility mode.
}
</script>
```

OR you can force IE to display as a specific version:

```
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" >
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" >
```

Microsoft has a good MSDN article that describes this in detail. [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: That's a useful tidbit.. Didn't realize you could force standards mode from HTML. Thanks!

Comment: Hi - Thanks for your reply - it does look like it's running in standards mode, no compatibility mode - added the meta tag just to see and it didn't change the behavior.

Comment: You can also force IE9 to display as IE8 or IE7.   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" >

Comment: forcing it to use ie8 does work - thanks so much for the suggestion.  I do wish I knew what the issue was though - !